# Is there a language and platform agnostic declarative GUI language that isn't XML?

Tags: user-interface, language-agnostic, cross-platform, declarative

Basically, I'm looking for a least common denominator declarative GUI language that would be perfectly suitable for rendering with JavaScript to HTML/CSS, with Python to wxPython and with C# to WinForms... emphasis on the least common denominator. Otherwise, I'm perfectly aware this is almost impossible. Basically, JSON for declarative GUIs rather than data.

Oh yeah, and the real kicker: no XML. Period. Ideally, the syntax would be something like Markdown where it doesn't look like code.

If you don't know of any such thing, you can just post some ideas on what you think it should look like and how you think it should (or could) work, because I was planning on creating one myself. I'm just making sure I'm not reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Why not xml? Is this for naive users?

Comment: I'm all for XML where XML is warrented.  Imho, it is NOT suitable for design type work; it is suited to mark-up, unambiguous markup exchange, and useful things for Machines to do. ;-)

Comment: hi @InstanceHunter, I need your GUI language that by now you've been working on for over 10 years, please post git link :-P

Comment: otherwise I'll have to make one, and like you I don't like to reinvent the wheel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's safe to say after 3 months that the answer is **no**.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're tired of XML.  If you don't like Snow (see above) try curl http://groups.csail.mit.edu/cag/curl/

Answer (score 1):

Qooxdoo is an awesome GUI technology for the web.  There is a new serialization project called Tartan Blueprint that allows the generation of Qooxdoo client apps from serialized JSON.  Its pure JSON and OO javascript.  No XML.  The JSON can be generated by hand or by any code that can generate valid JSON.  Take a look...

The announcement:
http://news.qooxdoo.org/the-week-in-qooxdoo-2009-10-02

Comment: Interesting, but I don't see how this is language and platform agnostic. Can I take this Blueprint JSON and turn it into a Python app?

Comment: Oh sorry.  I thought you were looking for an easy way to generate GUIs from python.  Basically you can dump a dict into json using something like SimpleJson and send into blueprint.  But, you do need to build the server side part that generates the dict.  Blueprint has a nested object structure so the generation of json can be accomplished using recursive functions quite easily.

Answer (score 0):

Well, HTML kind of aspires to that.  How about [wiki markup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Cheatsheet)?

Comment: HTML is essentially XML and the problem with wiki markup languages is that they don't include things like text boxes and drop-down boxes and buttons, nor ways to lay out forms usually.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [Snow](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgdl/)?